# C++ , can't get it to run hello world code

Tags: c++

First I was not able to install GWmin gcc. Now that I am done with that I have a new issue the build says there is nothing to build even when I have put a hello world programme in there.

```
#include <iostream>
   int main()
   {
        cout << "hello!! World\n"
   }
   return 0;
```

Another thing that I noticed it contrary to the video link I shared here my eclipse is not picking up a close bracket when I type in the opening bracket no color change of the word include after# pls help.

[A video i am following to learn c++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3t-5UtvDN0)

Comment: I think you should watch that video again.  Start at 4:30 and pay attention for at least three minutes.  Compare your code to their code.  What's different?

Comment: Learning C++ from videos seems to be error prone. Well I never tried so, being educating myself old school ways from books and practising. But your track seems to be a weak one!

Answer (score 2):

**First**,
try, (underneath #include) typing

```
using namespace std;
```

to even everything out, and I think you may want to change

```
cout<<"Hello!! World \n"
```

to

```
cout<<"Hello!! World \n"<< endl;
```

(last characters a lowercase L, in case your font type makes it look like a 1)

**Second**, make sure that you're using **g++**, instead of **gcc** (Happens to me all the time)

**Lastly**, if that doesn't work, move the **return 0;** into the brackets,

that should fix everything

Answer (score 0):

There are three mistakes in this small hello world program.

1. std namespace does not provide for `cout`. So change to `std::cout`.
2. semicolon(**;**) is missing, end of `cout` line.
3. `return` statement should inside curly brackets {}.

After making above changes your code

```
#include <iostream>
   int main()
   {
        std::cout << "hello!! World\n";
        return 0;
   }
```

You are using `\n` for new line. Since this is 'C++' code, It is recommended to use `std::endl` for new line.

Answer (score -1):

If you working with Eclipse on Windows platform, try to install TDM-GCC MinGW Compiler. It just a few clicks setup. Don't forget to choose MinGW compiler, when you create a new c++ project in Eclipse